# How do I tell if a class property has a public set (.NET)?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, reflection

I have this:

```
public string Log
        {
            get { return log; }
            protected set
            {
                if (log != value)
                {
                    MarkModified(PropertyNames.Log, log);
                    log = value;
                }
            }

        }
```

And my utility class for databinding does this:

```
PropertyInfo pi = ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyInfo(boundObjectType, sourceProperty);

if (!pi.CanWrite)
                SetReadOnlyCharacteristics(boundEditor);
```

But PropertyInfo.CanWrite does not care whether the set is publicly accessible, only that it exists.

How can I determine if there's a **public** set, not just **any** set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the suggested changes to ReflectionHelper in other answers is to call `pi.GetSetMethod(false)` and see if the result is null.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx). Something like

```
PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty("MyProperty", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call GetSetMethod on PropertyInfo, obtain MethodInfo and examine its properties, like IsPublic.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyInfo(), you presumably to a boundObjectType.GetType().GetProperties(), where the BindingFlags parameter apparently includes BindingFlags.NonPublic.  You want to specify just BindingFlags.Public

Comment: This won't work, property can be public, while its "set" can be private or internal.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's a  little hard to tell since you have a "ReflectionHelper" class where we cannot see the source.  However, my first guess is that you aren't properly setting the BindingFlags attribute when you call Type.GetProperty.  You need to OR in the Public enumeration flag to ensure that only Public values are returned.